# How to combine shape drawable and drawable into single drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapedrawable, android-runtime, layerdrawable

I am generating shape drawable and drawable runtime in android programmatically. What all I need is to combine two drawable into single drawable. I tried to implement through following methods, but nothing seems to work out.

**Sample code to combine two drawables into single using LayerDrawable**

```
public static LayerDrawable drawCircleWithIcon (Context context, int width, int height, int color,Drawable drawable) {

        ShapeDrawable oval = new ShapeDrawable (new OvalShape ());
        oval.setIntrinsicHeight (height);
        oval.setIntrinsicWidth (width);
        oval.getPaint ().setColor (color);

        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = drawable;
        layers[1] = oval;

        LayerDrawable composite1 = new LayerDrawable (layers);

        return composite1;
    }
```

**Arguments I am passing:**

```
width - width of the circle  
height - height of the circle  
color - color of the circle
drawable - icon that needs to be fit inside the ShapeDrawable (i.e. Round circle inside placed with icon)
```

**My requirement:**

I need to combine two drawables (one is ShapeDrawable and drawable). The output must be like as following

[image]

Kindly please help me with your solutions or alternate methods to merge two drawable into one drawable icon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use RoundedBitmapDrawable ?

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. How to use that???

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an imageview an set the properties backgroundDrawable and imageDrawable or imageResource.

```
yourImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(yourShape);
YourImageView.setImageDrawable(yourImage);
```

To adjust the drawable and keep aspect ratio try using, his methods.

```
yourImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
yourImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Due to this answer does't adjust to the question, if what you want is to create a single image combining multiple drawables, you can try something like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();

// Front image
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.frontImage);

// The rounded background
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, shapeDrawable);
RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res, background);
dr.setCornerRadius(Math.max(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight()) / 2.0f);

Bitmap combined = Bitmap.createBitmap(dr.getWidth(), dr.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Creates the combined drawable
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combined);
canvas.drawBitmap(dr,0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, dr.getWidht() / 2.0f, dr.getHeight() / 2.0f, null);
```

I have not tried the code above, but i'm showing something could help you.

Comment: No i need to generate it as single drawable because I need to set drawable for NavigationView icon

Comment: @Chandru I have edited the answer, you can check if it helps. Thanks

Comment: The first version setBackgroundDrawable() + setImageDrawable() does not work; but the second version using RoundedBitmapDrawable works fine.